# HSExposure() module is not callable

Tags: python, biopython

```
from Bio.PDB import *
parser=PDBParser()
structure=parser.get_structure('cal1','3CLN.pdb')
model=structure[0]
chain=model["A"]
hse=HSExposure()
expca=hse.calc_hs_exposure(model,option='CA3')
print expca[chain[40]]
```

When I execute this code, I'm getting this error:

```
File "D:\python\Core\pdb_2.py", line 6, in <module>
    hse=HSExposure()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone like me still looking for the answer:
Most tutorials seem to have this wrong. What worked for me was

```
exp_ca = HSExposureCA(model)  
res_id = residue.get_id()  
print(exp_ca[(chain.get_id(), res_id)])
```

Please note that HSEalpha is undefined for the first and last residues of a chain.

Comment: Great... but what is the returned three-element tuple? Is it HSE &alpha;&beta; u(p), HSE &alpha;&beta; d(own) and a zero for good measure??

Answer (score 2):

`HSExposure` is a module, not a class, so you can't instantiate it. There's a [bunch of classes in that module](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.HSExposure-module.html), so I assume you want one of them.

Comment: Ya, i want to use HSExposureCA but if i wrote that instead of HSExposure() then again it gives error.